# SSIS returns an incorrect error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb

I created SSIS package, which created table `MyTable` in SQL Server with a column `BaseVariantVersionID`. Program first inserts data into this table.

At the end of the package, I should drop column `BaseVariantVersionID` from the table.

First debug is OK. But on second attempt, SSIS returns a validation error. It doesn't allow to recreate the table with `BaseVariantVersionID`, because on next step package cannot made insert in column, which now is not presented.

Maybe you know some property to disable current db checking?

**Update**

I drop column after all steps.
And on first step I recreated DB with column. 
But system returns error - looks like it use existing table for validation.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough information to recreate the issue.   Show the code that causes the error, and the exact error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be several issues I can think of.

You must absolutely delete the table if it already exists prior to creating it at the beginning of the package.

Example Execute SQL Task:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('MyTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE MyTable
GO

CREATE TABLE MyTable (etc...) GO
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN (etc...) GO
```

Second, you can set `DelayValidation = True` in the Data Flow Task Properties Window (this is on the bottom right usually after clicking a Dataflow Task in the design area). That delays validation until run time.

If at the moment, you have a missing field error, you can add the column manually in SQL Server Management Studio, then double-click the task with the error and any missing field error should disappear (now that the column exists).  After that you can save the package and exit.

Comment: Yes, on first step I recreated table. Than, I load information for this and other table. Finally, I drop column.

Comment: I set `DelayValidation  = True` and now all works as expected. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

For an Execute SQL Task, you can set [BypassPrepare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.tasks.executesqltask.executesqltask.bypassprepare.aspx) to True.  Sometimes that will allow you to design and build a package which doesn't validate at design time, but will validate okay at run time.

But I have to question the need to create columns and tables at run time.  Are you sure you need to do this?  It is a more typical use case to have SSIS move data around in existing table structures, not create them at run time.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your description correctly, you're dropping the *column* on the first pass, then getting an error trying to recreate the *table* on the second pass? You will get an error on run #2 if you try to create a table that already exists, even if it doesn't have "SomeColumn" in it.

You'll need to drop the table if you're going to want to recreate it or change your code to add the column back if the table exists.

Comment: No, I drop column after all steps. And on first step I recreated DB with column. But system returns error - looks like it use existing table for validation. See image in next comment

Comment: Your description and the sample beg the question why do you drop the column then recreate the table with the column at next execution.


I think @criticalfix has identified what you need to do to get the package to validate.